# Embedded design with USB 3.1

Tags: microcontroller, usb, usb-host

I am trying to design a system that will transfer data between two storage devices on a PCB, preferably using USB 3.1 as speed is a major concern in this design. However, my understanding is that I would need something to serve as a host controller to actually transfer the data between the storage medium. In my research I've been unable to find any microcontroller that has USB 3.1 capabilities. Is there any other way I can transfer the data at high speeds, or a method of using a microcontroller with a separate USB host controller without any significant loss of speed?

Comment: No, you will need a host controller supporting at least two devices.

Comment: What sort of specs would the host controller need in order to reach maximum speed? Can I do it with a microcontroller, or would I need something beefier?

Comment: You can start here: https://www.cypress.com/file/206291/download

Comment: What kind of "storage devices on a PCB" do you have? Why do you believe that USB 3.1 should be the interface?

Comment: @EugeneSh.The Cypress device looks perfect, thank you!

Comment: @Ale..chenski I need to transfer data between UFS storage devices as fast as possible. I've found a USB-UFS bridge as a starting point, so that seemed like the easiest way to transfer the data between devices.

Comment: Flash drive interface is much simpler than USB. There are ton's of MCU that support two or more flash ports. USB is designed to drive devices over long wires. Using USB for embedded purposes is usually a hack.

Comment: What do you mean by "Flash drive interface"? What protocol is that? And what speed would the data transfer be at?

Comment: Sorry, I confused eMMC/SD flash with UFS. UFS is just taking off. If you really up to UFS, you need to look into Qualcomm of Samsung processors. If you are not a big player, forget UFS. If you are a big player you should already know this by contact ing Toshiba UFS memory division and the above CPU vendors.